# UITextField with a text length counter

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

Well the title says it mostly:

Is there a ready to go `UITextField` component out there that can take a number (maximum text length) in the label? It would be also cool if the number can also be displayed.

Is there a component out there?

What I would like to have:

1. Limit input by custom text length
2. Number of left character gets displayed inside the TextField
3. Paste prevention

Comment: Just make use of the UITextFieldDelegate method textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:replacementString: and you can easily achieve that

Comment: @manecosta I know but I need something more flexible. I updated my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I created [this](https://github.com/JonathanGurebo/UITextFieldLimit) UITextFieldLimit subclass:

- Multiple textfields supported
- Set the text length limit
- Paste prevention
- Displays a label of left characters inside the textfield, get hidden when you stop editing.
- Delegate
- Shake animation when no characters left.

Grab the `UITextFieldLimit.h` and `UITextFieldLimit.m` from this GitHub repository:

https://github.com/JonathanGurebo/UITextFieldLimit

and begin to test!

Mark your storyboard-created UITextField and link it to my subclass using the Identity Inspector:

[image: Identity Inspector]

Then you can link it to an IBOutlet and set the limit(default is 10).

---

Your ViewController.h file should contain: (if you wan't to modify the setting, like the limit)

```
#import "UITextFieldLimit.h"

/.../

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextFieldLimit *textFieldLimit; // <--Your IBOutlet
```

---

Your ViewController.m file should `@synthesize textFieldLimit`.

---

Set the text length limit in your ViewController.m file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [textFieldLimit setLimit:25];// <-- and you won't be able to put more than 25 characters in the TextField.
}
```

Hope the class helps you. Good luck!

Comment: So thx first for all your help. Unfornately I'm getting the same (`BAD_EXE`) Error on your component. It's kinda crazy: when I type something in the TextField on the second, max third, character it crashes. But if I type with my keyboard (not over the touchscreen) on my mac it doesn't crash. Can you reproduce it? (Tested on iPhone 5s and Simulator 4inch 32bit)

Comment: Yeay, I didn't test with the simulator touchscreen. Same crash for me when using a simulator touchscreen. Works great on the device. iOS Simulator bug?

Comment: On my iPhone 5s iOS 7.1 it also crashes.. I got no clue.. BTW i'll make pull request on github. Check it out.

Comment: same crash on iPhone 4...

Comment: It works great for me on real devices, i'm going to check it out.

Comment: On what device do you have test it

Comment: But I discovered, when bringing up the emoji keyboard the app will crash on the real device.

Comment: I'll accept the answer, let's move the bug fixing to github. I'm getting off-topic down votes, ok?

Answer (score 5):

SEE MY OTHER ANSWER FOR A GOOD SUBCLASS INSTEAD.

I added a UILabel subview to the TextField to show the character limit.

It will:
* Limit input by custom text length
* show the character limit in a UILabel subview inside UITextField.
* Paste prevention

RESULT:
[image: Empty textField (20 characters left)]
or
[image: three characters (17 characters left)]

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize textField1;
UILabel *yourLabel;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    yourLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(textField1.bounds.size.width-18, 12, 300, 20)];//Change your size, you will need to experiment with the size

    [yourLabel setTextColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [yourLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [yourLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName: @"Trebuchet MS" size: 14.0f]];
    [yourLabel setText:@""];
    [textField1 addSubview:yourLabel];
    textField1.delegate=self;
    [self textField:textField1 shouldChangeCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 0) replacementString:@""];//To change the limit label
}

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    int MAXLENGTH=20;

    NSString *newText = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if(newText.length>MAXLENGTH) {
        return NO;
    }
    [yourLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",MAXLENGTH-newText.length]];

    return YES;
}
```

I hope this fit your needs and get you started.

Don't forget to subscribe to the `UITextFieldDelegate`. In your .h file, declare:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITextFieldDelegate>// -- < UITextFieldDelegate
```

Comment: You should have the if(newText.length>=MAXLENGTH) line before setting text on yourLabel. Like you have it right now, if someone pastes more than MAXLENGTH characters, while it won't allow the edition, yourLabel will change to -X characters left.

Comment: Also, it should be > instead of >=, or you're only allowing 19 chars.

Comment: Hey guys thanks for the sample! I was asking myself if its possible to make it as a component - subclassing - (just .h & .m). So I don't have to use the delegate methods in every viewController and I don't have to check the TextFields (e.g. in multiple TextFields).

Comment: Yeah, I think that is possible

Comment: I made a [Project](https://github.com/deada92/CountTextField) with the help of your code, but if I try to type the third character it crashes. Could you check it out?

Comment: See my new answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23024391/uitextfield-with-a-text-length-counter/23035971#23035971 (or scroll)

Answer (score 1):

Requirements 1 and 3 are straight-froward with the delegate method:

```
// maxLength is a publicly assignable property

- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    // this covers paste, also
    NSString *candidateString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if (candidateString.length > self.maxLength) return NO;

    [self updateCaptionSizeForText:candidateString];

    // requirement 2
    [self updateCharsRemainingLabel:candidateString.length];
    return YES;
}
```

Requirement 2 can be achieved by adding a label and updating it's value as follows:

```
- (void)updateCharsRemainingLabel:(NSInteger)currentLength {
    NSInteger remaining = self.maxLength - currentLength;
    self.charsRemainingLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", remaining];
}
```